# Why is .replace method not working for me?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using a simple .replace method on a simple pandas dataframe. I believe I am coding it correct.  What am I missing?

I have given the documentation a look, but I can't find the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
data =[1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.replace('5', 'T')
print(df)
```

I would like the value of 5 to be replaced with a T. However, nothing happens. I also do not get any error.

Comment: `df.replace(5, 'T',inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method returns the new dataframe, and does not modify it. You can either assign the modified dataframe (`df = df.replace('5', 'T')`) or use the `inplace` argument.